# Compare two strings in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am using free marker and i am returning response from application as string i need to compare the response with static some string . Here is the way of doing.
`${users.isValid}` it is returning "true" in but i am not able to compare this variable form my variable.Code i am using is :

```
<#if ${parameters.isvalid}>
```

It is valid data

```
<#else>
```

It is Invalid data

```
</#if>
```

What is possible way to close this issue thanks in advance.

Comment: It's `<#if parameters.isValid>`. You can't have `${...}` there, and it gives you a parsing error. If you still have a problem, please include error message.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have used the following syntax to compare two string values in freemarker.

`<#if parameters.isvalid == "true">`

Answer (score 3):

```
//if isvalid is a string variable...
<#if parameters?? && parameters.isvalid?? && parameters.isvalid="true">
     blah blah
<#else>
     lah lah
</#if>

//if isvalid is a boolean variable...
<#if parameters?? && parameters.isvalid?? && parameters.isvalid=true>
     blah blah
<#else>
     lah lah
</#if>
```

[See the deails](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison)

Answer (score 1):

In freemarker template you cannot use interpolations inside if statement.
It's a frequent mistake to use interpolations on places where they needn't/shouldn't/can't be used. Interpolations work only in text sections (e.g. `<h1>Hello ${name}!</h1>`) and in string literals (e.g. `<#include "/footer/${company}.html">`).

A typical WRONG usage is `<#if ${big}>...</#if>`, which will give syntactical error. You should simply write `<#if big>...</#if>`. Also, `<#if "${big}">...</#if>` is WRONG, since it converts the parameter value to string and the if directive wants a boolean value, so it will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

This is neat and worked for me

```
${("123"=="1234")?string("yees","noo")}
```